# Unable to execute Excel SQL Query from Python application

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

From my Python application, I am trying to open an ADODB connection of Excel. The code is as below:

```
# Create Connection object and connect to database.
ado_conn = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('ADODB.Connection')
ado_conn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\\Test1.xlsx; Extended Properties ='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'";

ado_conn.Open()

# Now create a RecordSet object and open a table
oRS = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('ADODB.Recordset')
oRS.ActiveConnection = ado_conn    # Set the recordset to connect thru oConn

oRS.Open("SELECT * FROM [Orders]")
```

When I debug the application, it throws the error:

> com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Access Database Engine', "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Orders'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Orders' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.", None, 5003011, -2147217865), None)

In the Excel sheet the connection string looks like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Orders;Extended Properties=""
```

The Command Text is:

```
Select * from [Orders]
```

Even if the connection is there, it is throwing this error.

How to execute the above Excel query from Python application?

**Edit: Excel connection screenshot added below**

[image]

Comment: So you're using Python, to call a SQL query from Excel, that queries an Access database?

Comment: @JerryM. It is SAP database.

Answer (score 1):

To use the Jet/ACE SQL Engine to query Excel workbooks, you must use the `$` address referencing which can be extended for specific cell ranges:

```sql
SELECT * from [Orders$]

SELECT * from [Orders$B4:Y100]
```

---

With that said, consider querying Excel workbooks directly from Python with either OLEDB provider or ODBC driver version and avoid the COM interfacing of Window's ADO object:

```
# OLEDB PROVIDER
import adodbapi
conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" \
                        "Data Source = C:\\Test1.xlsx;" \
                        "Extended Properties ='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM [Orders$]")    
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)

# ODBC DRIVER
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" \
                      "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Excel.xlsx;")    
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM [Orders$]")    
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Comment: When I give '$' in query, it throws error: Sales_Report$ is an invalid name

Comment: Make sure *Sales_Order* exists as actual worksheet. I see *Order* in your post above. Edit accordingly. And please report exact error as traceback of API (adodbapi or pyodbc) Same as above?

Comment: I have edited original post. Added screenshot. I want to execute the SQL query associated with the connection.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying. Did you run `oRS.Open("SELECT * FROM [Orders$]")`?  What was specific error? This solution does not involve doing *anything* in Excel but make direct SQL query calls. Also, the latter solution avoids the `win32` COM layer which is unnecessary as Python can query workbooks without Windows' ADO object using its own standard API ([PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)) which includes modules like pyodbc. I assure you `$` works as above shows.

Comment: Here I am confused. I change the sheet name to Sheet1 and changed to: oRS.Open("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"). It worked. No issues. Let me clarify the issue. In the screenshot in OP, you see an SQL Query: "Select * from Orders". I actually want to execute this. The problem is that there is a PowerQuery. If due to authentication issues, the Power Query fails, I want this exception to be handled in Python. This is still not working.

Comment: Possibly *Orders* conflicts with the PowerQuery object name or some other named range in workbook. Try something other than *Sheet1* to check. If your sheet name issue is resolved and it includes the data you want to query, what is wrong with the solution?